# Finding the largest prime factor? (Doesn't work in large number?)

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++, and I just finished reading chapter 1 of the C++ Primer. So I try the problem of computing the largest prime factor, and I find out that my program works well up to a number of sizes 10e9 but fails after that e.g.600851475143 as it always returns a wired number e.g.2147483647 when I feed any large number into it. I know a similar question has been asked many times, I just wonder why this could happen to me. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I guess the reason has to do with some part of my program that is not capable to handle some large number.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int val = 0, temp = 0;
    std::cout << "Please enter: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> val;
    for (int num = 0; num != 1; val = num){
        num = val/2;
        temp = val;
        while (val%num != 0)
            --num;
    }
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You hit the [integer limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647)...

Comment: @user1810087 how to solve it?

Comment: Use another type than int. you could use int64 which gives you a max up to [9,223,372,036,854,775,807](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)) if that would be enough for your case.

Comment: What happens here is probably an int overflow. This means that the number you're trying to compute exceeds the maximum. Try to use an `std::uint64_t` instead. It might work a bit more but will still be limited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `int` type is 32 bits (like on most systems). The largest value a two's complement signed 32 bit value can store is `2 ** 31 - 1`, or 2147483647. Take a look [at `man limits.h`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/limits.h.0p.html) if you want to know the constants defining the limits of your types, and/or use larger types (e.g. `unsigned` would double your range at basically no cost, `uint64_t` from `stdint.h`/`inttypes.h` would expand it by a factor of 8.4 billion and only cost something meaningful on 32 bit systems).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! it is good to know that.

Answer (score 2):

`2147483647` isn't a wired number its `INT_MAX` which is defined in `climits` header file. This happens when you reach maximum capacity of an `int`.

You can use a bigger data type such as `std::size_t` or `unsigned long long int`, for that purpose, which have a maximum value of `18446744073709551615`.

Comment: only minimum widths of integer types are defined. The actual width can be larger